# Moving file with Java changes directory to .eml

Tags: java, file

I am using the following code to move a `.eml` file from one directory to another:

```
if(Files.exists(Paths.get(newDirectoryPath))){
            try {
                Files.move(Paths.get(filePath), Paths.get(newDirectoryPath), REPLACE_EXISTING);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }else{
            new File(newDirectoryPath).mkdir(); 
            moveFile(filePath, newDirectoryPath); 
        }
```

The directory is created okay, but when I move a file into the new directory, the directory becomes an `.eml` file. Why is this? What am I missing?

UPDATE:

Here are the values when I debug:

```
filePath = "/Users/absolute/path/to/my/file/myfile.eml";
newDirectoryPath = "/Users/absolute/path/to/my/new/directory/CompleteKsc"
```

Comment: What values do your variables contain when you run this and what is the expected result?

Comment: @KErlandsson see edited question. Everything is as expected. Expected results is to move this file, along with multiple other files into the new directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **target** in `Files.move(source, target, options)` is the actual target of the move. With `REPLACE_EXISTING` your call will remove the existing target (your directory) and then move the source to that name.
A directory will only be removed if it's *empty**, otherwise the call with throw a DirectoryNotEmptyException.

If you want to move the file to a file with the same name ***in*** the directory, you have to append the filename to the target.

The [javadoc for move](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) has an example of using `newdir.resolve(...)` to do exactly what you want.

Converting your original code to follow that example gives me this:

```
public void moveFile(String source, String targetDir)
{
    Path dirpath = Paths.get(targetDir);

    if (Files.exists(dirpath)) {

        Path target = dirpath.resolve(targetDir);

        try {
            Files.move(Paths.get(source), dirpath.resolve(target), REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        new File(targetDir).mkdir();
        moveFile(source, targetDir);
    }
}
```

---

`*` "empty" includes directories that have only meta-files in them; for example on Mac OS X a directory that contains just the **.DS_Store** metadata file is considered empty.
From the javadoc: *" In some implementations a directory has entries for special files or links that are created when the directory is created. In such implementations a directory is considered empty when only the special entries exist."*

Comment: You might want to add that the directory will only be removed if it is empty. If it is non-empty an exception will be thrown.